# observablecollection of observablecollection declaration

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection, dependency-properties

Somehow, this is not working at runtime (but it is compiling) :

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedVideoFileNamesProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedVideoFileNames", typeof(ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<string>>), typeof(CMiX_UI), 
        new PropertyMetadata(new[]{new ObservableCollection<string>(),
                                   new ObservableCollection<string>(),
                                   new ObservableCollection<string>(),
                                   new ObservableCollection<string>(),
                                   new ObservableCollection<string>(),
                                   new ObservableCollection<string>()}));
    [Bindable(true)]
    public ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<string>> SelectedVideoFileNames
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<string>>)this.GetValue(SelectedVideoFileNamesProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(SelectedVideoFileNamesProperty, value); }
    }
```

Why ? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't be running as you assign an array of ObservableCollection of string `ObservableCollection<string>[]` to be the default value for an `ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<string>>`. If you write your code like this:

```
        ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<string>> o = new[]{new ObservableCollection<string>(),
                               new ObservableCollection<string>(),
                               new ObservableCollection<string>(),
                               new ObservableCollection<string>(),
                               new ObservableCollection<string>(),
                               new ObservableCollection<string>()};
```

It will give you a design-time error that says:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection[]' to 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection>'

Instead, you can:

```
        ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<string>> o = new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<string>> {new ObservableCollection<string>(),
                               new ObservableCollection<string>(),
                               new ObservableCollection<string>(),
                               new ObservableCollection<string>(),
                               new ObservableCollection<string>(),
                               new ObservableCollection<string>()};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your type is defined as an

```
ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<string>>
```

Yet you are setting the default as:

```
new[]{new ObservableCollection<string>(),
                               new ObservableCollection<string>(),
                               new ObservableCollection<string>(),
                               new ObservableCollection<string>(),
                               new ObservableCollection<string>(),
                               new ObservableCollection<string>()}))
```

Which is an array of observable collections. You need:

```
new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<String()>> {new ObservableCollection<string>(),
                               new ObservableCollection<string>(),
                               new ObservableCollection<string>(),
                               new ObservableCollection<string>(),
                               new ObservableCollection<string>(),
                               new ObservableCollection<string>()}))
```